# Rails application can't reach remote PostgreSQL server (proxy, VirtualBox)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, proxy, virtualbox

I have a Windows 7 PC with Forefront TMG proxy. There is a VirtualBox virtual machine installed with Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit) guest OS. I'm not a seasoned Unix-user, so I tried to configure Ubuntu's network through GUI window.

After several tries I wound up with these settings:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/in4yR.jpg

All works fine now. I can use browser and git and do various network stuff. But!

I have a Rails application, which uses a remote PostgreSQL database. When I start my Rails server, it throws this exception:

```
Puma caught this error: could not connect to server: Network is unreachable
Is the server running on host "this_is_the_host_url" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
(PG:ConnectionBad)
```

This applications works fine on the other PC with similar Windows 7 and VB Ubuntu, but without a proxy. Also I tried to reach the remote DB-server from my host Win7 with PGAdmin - all works fine, even with proxy. The issue is somewhere between my Ubuntu guest OS and my Windows host OS.

Should I configure proxy settings in Ubuntu in a different way?
Any other way to resolve this issue?

Traceroute shows this:

```
1 10.0.2.2 (10.0.2.2) 0.638 ms 0.577 ms 0.549 ms
2 10.0.2.2 (10.0.2.2) 29.369 ms !N 53.000 ms !N 75.644 !N
```

As I can get it, 10.0.2.2 is my host OS ip.

I searched through the web, but all I could get belongs to the opposite side: to reach to the proxied VB Ubuntu, not from it.

Comment: Can you access postresql from prompt ? Try this `telnet localhost 5432`and see if you're able to connect. If you're not, this is problem due to `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` bad configurations. You'll need to search for how to make your postgrsql available over network.

Comment: Why localhost? The PostgreSQL server is remote, it's not on my localhost.

Comment: telnet _database_url_ 5432 gives the same error: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable.
But why I can connect to it with my PGAdmin from host OS (Windows 7). Database administrator swears that he allows all the Internet, and the issue is within my environment.

Comment: If telnet does not work, it means there's a connection problem between your machine and the database's machine. You take a look in that. It's not a rails problem.

Comment: This Ubuntu configuration, You replaced this "proxy" with the actual proxy address, right?

Comment: Actually, this is the proxy's name. I have replaced only the DB server IP.
I believe the problem is somewhere in the Ubuntu or Virtual Machine settings, because routing stops at host's node.